# Let Apache2 fire a Script located on a Client

Tags: python, php, linux, apache2, pyserial

lets say I have a Webserver (apache2) running, on this server runs my Website (HTML, PHP, JS, CSS). This site calculates and displays data. On a ButtonClickevent I want to execute a python script, which is located on my client (connected to a serial device). How do I communicate for example in exec(), system(), passthru(), ... that my script to be executed is not on the server, but on my client.

Problem is, that my Scripts always select the ttyUSB0 from my server-maschine and not from my client.

Next step is to send the output from my serial-data ClientScript back to the webserver and let it show or send to my database.

I havent found any solution to do this, or I just looked for the wrong aspects. If anybody got some ideas or references please help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: _"How do I communicate for example in exec(), system(), passthru(), ... that my script to be executed is not on the server, but on my client."_ - you simply don't, because that is of course not possible. Would be an absolutely ridiculous security risk, if any web server could trigger any scripts to run on my client machine, based on nothing more than that I visited a web page hosted on that server.

Comment: yea i understand that, but is there some sort of a work-around to achieve a similar result to display calculate and communicate with serial-data with clients and servers?

Comment: You would need to make the client machine itself execute the python script, and then catch the result and pass it on to your web server.

Comment: I guess you could run a webserver on your "client" machine (static IP) and trigger a webhook/URL on that server/IP to run your python script which would then communicate back to your "server" webserver

Comment: but if i want to run like 10 machines connected to serial devices i cant install 10 webservers and make them communicate with the master server displaying the data that seems wrong isnt it? are there any other ways to get a data transfer from multiple machines controlled by a website running on apache2?